# What does the line, "In the halls of justice, the only justice is in the halls" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, quotations

This is a famous Lenny Bruce quote but I am unable to understand it. 
What does it mean?

> The only justice is in the halls, i.e. outside the courtroom.
>   There is no justice inside the courtroom; it's in the "halls" outside the formal proceedings.
>   Deals are made "in the halls" outside the courtroom.
>   You get your best deal "in the halls" or "outside the courtroom". That's where you get justice; by negotiating, dealing, making your best deal.

Comment: I think It implies there is no any justice. I am not sure, I've inferred that form the negative suggestion of "only" (or negative impression). Lets see what the native people say ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a mild play on words: the "halls of justice" are the imposing buildings where Law is carried out, a metonymy for Law itself in all its grandeur and majesty. Bruce uses the word *halls* in a very different sense as the corridors which link the courtrooms: to say that justice is only in the halls outside the courtroom implies that there is no justice within the courtroom.

Comment: The corridors are where the lawyers cut deals (such as _plea bargains_). I don't think Lenny would have considered that "justice", either.

Comment: @BrianHitchcock It's not one of his great lines. But great lines weren't his thing.